# Caps Lock key not working in VMware Player

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, vmware-player, capslock

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 as a guest on VMware Player on Win 7. Recently I noticed that the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key has no effect in the VM. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key works fine in capitalizing the typed keys.

How can I make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to work?

Answer (score 0):

The Capslock-Key is not recorded through software, that is, it cannot be read by some programs. Via Send Key -> Capslock you can send a virtual Capslock-Stroke to the VM.

Source: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004192

Comment: Thanks. The page you link to seems to deal with the "Fusion" product, not the free "Player". I can't locate that "Send Key" menu in my Player.